# Using multiple values in a SQL column - Is it possible (or even a good idea)?

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-design

If you were creating a todo list app where users can sign up and manage their own todo list, would it be better to:

**Option 1**: Have a `todo_lists` table in the database. There will be a username, password, and todo list items column.

**Option 2**: When a user creates an account, their username and password will be recorded in a users table. Then, a new table would be created automatically created, called `(insert your username)_list`, where their todo list items would be stored.

The problem with option 1 is I do not know if it is possible to store multiple values in a single column. (I couldn't find any good information on if SQL supports any sort of arrays.)

The problem with option 2 is I'm not sure if creating a new table for every user is bad performance-wise.

Comment: You need **Option 3:** One table (`users`) with user data and one table (`todo_items`) with one row per todo item and a foreign key to the `users` table.

Comment: Clever! That makes a lot more sense.

Answer (score 0):

If the records all have the same structure, then they should be stored in the same table.

SQL is optimized to handle large tables, rather than large number of parallel tables.  And, there are many other advantages when querying the data -- if the data is in multiple tables, then you will need to use dynamic SQL for many otherwise simple queries.

There are a handful of situations where separate tables -- even separate tables in different databases -- are desirable.  These mostly center on security-intensive applications and such considerations are probably not important for your needs.

Comment: Thanks! Very helpful.